# Trying to set a GregorianCalendar variable = to another GregroianCalendar variable + 4 years

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I am having through getting setting the value of a GregorianCalendar to that of another one + 4 years.  I see there s the add method in the class but this accepts an int and I am trying to pass a GregorianCalendar type.

```
public GregorianCalendar getEnrollmentDate(GregorianCalendar enrollmentDate){
    return enrollmentDate;
}
public void setProjectedGraduationDate(GregorianCalendar projectedGraduationDate){
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(this.enrollmentDate);
    projectedGraduationDate = cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 4);
}
```

The value that I am trying to add years to is "enrollmentDate"

Is this possible, the "setTime" method accepts a "Date" time, not a GregorianCalendar though.

Comment: you should **not** reassign parameters into your fonction

Comment: How do you add something to the input parm when you never reference it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public setProjectedGraduationDate(GregorianCalendar projectedGraduationDate){
    projectedGraduationDate.setTime(this.enrollmentDate);
    projectedGraduationDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 4);
}
```

Comment: This is basically what I ended up with       public void setProjectedGraduationDate(GregorianCalendar projectedGraduationDate){
        projectedGraduationDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 4);
        this.projectedGraduationDate = projectedGraduationDate;
     }

Comment: @programmerNOOB - It's unwise to use the same variable name as both a local variable/parameter and an instance field name.

Answer (score 1):

just execute [`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) to get `Date` instance out of `GregorianCalendar`

Comment: The date is going to come from user input and then I will add 4 years to that.  Wouldn't getTime() get the current time?  not necessarily what the user would enter right?

Answer (score 0):

The `add` method of the `GregorianCalendar` class is void, so you can't assign a call to it to a variable.

If your intention is to modify the `GregorianCalendar` object that you're passing in to your method, then you'd want to write

```
projectedGraduationDate.add(calendar.YEAR,4);
```

but this would require setting `projectedGraduationDate` to the right value first.